# jQuery drag events being fired in different order based on direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, drag-and-drop

I am building a file browser where users have the ability to drag and drop folders to move them. There are some permissions that each user has that allow them to modify the folder structure. When a user drags a folder to move it, but do not have permission to change that particular folder structure, an icon is shown to inform the user that the action is invalid.

The icon is being shown correctly when a folder is being dragged down the folder tree, but it is not being shown when the folder is dragged up.

I noticed that this was being caused by the order of the dropout and dropover events was switched based on the drag direction. When dragging down, dropout is first followed by dropover. When dragging up the order is reversed. This is causing the classes applied in the dropover function to be removed in the dropout function.

Is there a way to ensure that dropout is fired before dropover?

Here are the event handlers

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dropTarget = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var $el = $(element);
        var eligibilityHandler = allBindings.get("canDrop");

        $el.on("dropover", function (event, ui) {
            if (!eligibilityHandler(ko.dataFor(element), ko.dataFor(ui.draggable[0]))) {
                $el.addClass('invalid-drop-target');
                $(ui.helper).addClass('invalid-drag-target');
             } else {
                $el.addClass('valid-drop-target');
                $(ui.helper).addClass('valid-drag-target');
             }
         });
         $el.on("dropout", function (event, ui) {
             $el.removeClass('invalid-drop-target');
             $(ui.helper).removeClass('invalid-drag-target');
             $el.removeClass('valid-drop-target');
             $(ui.helper).removeClass('valid-drag-target');
         });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should do:

1. Ensure that where you're going to drag the folder is not the folder daughter're dragging.
2. to drag the folder you check the id of the destination folder and
   set it as parent folder of the folder you are dragging.

ajax refills and you have updated the new structure of the tree.

The above applies to move a folder position in any type of tree.